# AttributeError: Extension instance has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python

Here is the script..

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

nmap = Extension('nmap',sources = ['nmap/nmap.py', 
                           'nmap/__init__.py', 'nmap/example.py'])

from nmap import *

setup (
    name = 'python-nmap',
    version = nmap.__version__,
    author = 'Alexandre Norman',
    author_email = 'norman@xael.org',
    license ='gpl-3.0.txt',
    keywords="nmap, portscanner, network, sysadmin",)
```

... and i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nmap.py", line 6, in <module>
    from nmap import *
  File "C:\Python27\nmap.py", line 17, in <module>
    version = nmap.__version__,
AttributeError: Extension instance has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: Edit your post using backticks ` surrounding all double-underscores so we can tell when you meant to use the dunder and when (if at all) you wanted to bold something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here.

1. Your `nmap` package isn't an extension, it's a pure-Python package; don't create an `Extension` object for it. Python extension are written in [C or C++](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html).
2. You're trying to access `nmap.__version__`, presumably because you defined that variable in `nmap/__init__.py`, but `nmap` here is that `Extension` object you created; it's trying to access the variable from the wrong thing.
3. Even if you remove the `Extension` object, you still wouldn't be able to access `nmap.__version__`, because you imported your package incorrectly; you meant to use `import nmap`.
4. You never actually pass your package to `setup`, so `distutils` won't know about it. There are a few examples of how to do that [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package).

The [`distutils` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html) is pretty big, but it's a good idea to read through all of it at least once.